# Check if token is nft and make sure it's not scam. Is it possible to do it partialy off-chain?

Tags: solana, metaplex

I am trying to understand metaplex standard. And in version 1.1 there was added filed `token_standard` to metadata acount and in that case it's easy to check if mint is fungible or not (in definition of metaplex).

But in version 1.0 I need to checked `mint_authority` filed of mint account (possible representing NFT). My question is: is it enough to check it off-chain or I must also ensure that this account exist and is owned by **Token Metadata Program**?

```rust
// assume that this mint has decimals = 0 and supply = 1.
let edition_pda = Pubkey::find_program_address(['metadata', token_metadata_program_id, mint_id, 'edition']);
if mint_authority == edition_pda {
  // This is NFT
} else {
  // This can be SCAM
}
```

Or maybe I am completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since Solana Program's are stateless it is best to validate all the things in and out of your program